# Dragging item from one div to another and sorting

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui-draggable

I have an x amount of small div's (let's call them `inner-div`) and a y amount of `container-div`'s.

I want the ability to drag `inner-div`'s to other `container-div`'s and have them sort with whatever is currently in that div.

I already have my div's, and the draggable feature added.

The `container-div`'s are created like this:

```
if($('#' + containter).length > 0) {
    //do nothing
} else {
    $('.info').append(
        $('<div>').attr({
            'id' : containter,
            'class' : 'container-div'
        }).html('<h3>' + title + '</h3>')
    );
}
```

And the `inner-div`'s are created like this:

```
$('#' + container).append(
    $('<div>').attr({
        class: 'inner-div'
    }).html('<img src="' + img + '">&nbsp;' + name).draggable({
        opacity: 0.7,
        helper: "clone"
    })
);
```

I want to know, how can I move an `inner-div` to another `container-div` and have it "snap" into place?

Comment: Have you looked at http://jqueryui.com/droppable/ and tried anything?  Also, `DIV` elements can contain anything... how do you want to define the sorting?

Comment: I've never actually noticed that there is a droppable function.

Comment: Glad you know now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can set the dragging and dropping.

```
    $('.inner-div').draggable({containment: 'body'});        

    $('.container-div').droppable({accept: '.inner-div'});

    $('.container-div').on('drop', function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append(ui.draggable);
        $(ui.draggable).css({left: '0', top: '0'});
    });
```

Comment: does exactly what I want it to do. How can I animate the css? So that it smoothly moves from where I drop it to the correct position.

Comment: under the .css line, or replace the .css line with something like this `$(ui.draggable).animate({left: '20px', 'top': '50px'}, 1200);`

Comment: Hmmm, tried that, it jumps offscreen and then slides into position. Thanks though, I'll play around with it a bit.

Comment: @DarkRanger Yea, it's just an example. So if you're still having problems getting it to work how you want after messing with it, just start a new question.